# Get parent node using child node lxml python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

For this `xml`,

```
 xmldata="""
    <locations>

    <continent region="Africa" >
        <country id="84" countryname="Algeria" ></country>
    </continent>

    <continent region="Asia" >
        <country id="84" countryname="India" ></country>
    </continent>

    <continent region="America" >
        <country id="84" countryname="Mexico" ></country>
    </continent>

</locations>
"""
```

I am trying to get region name using country name , If country name is `India` then code should return `Asia`.

What I have tried ,

```
import lxml.etree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
flag=False
continent=""
country=""
for neighbor in root.iter('continent'):
    for i in neighbor.iter("country"):
        if i.attrib.get('countryname')=="India":
            flag=True
            continent=neighbor.attrib.get('region')
            country=i.attrib.get('countryname')
    if flag==True:
        break
print 'Continent is ',continent , 'And country is ', country
```

This code works , but it is not convenient way to do this.

How can i achieve this using `xpath` expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `//continent[./country/@countryname="India"]/@region` xpath expression:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as ET
>>> xmldata="""
... <locations>
... 
... <continent region="Africa" >
...     <country id="84" countryname="Algeria" ></country>
... </continent>
... 
... <continent region="Asia" >
...     <country id="84" countryname="India" ></country>
... </continent>
... 
... <continent region="America" >
...     <country id="84" countryname="Mexico" ></country>
... </continent>
... 
... </locations>
... """
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
>>> print root.xpath('//continent[./country/@countryname="India"]/@region')
['Asia']
```

Comment: Thanks , can you please give me some links for learning `xpath` experssions ?

Comment: @Fledgling don't like to refer to w3c schools but there is a lot of [info](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) there. Also, you can experiment with the xpaths online, see [xpathtester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath).